# Запретить выбор определенных строк в DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть грид

```
 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyObservableCollection, Mode=OneWay}" 
                SelectionMode="Extended" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedValue, Mode=OneWayToSource}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" Width="40*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" Binding="{Binding TypeText, Mode=OneWay}" Width="10*" />            
            </DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="true или false"/>                   
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
        </DataGrid>
```

Хочу чтобы в зависимости от свойства ReadOnly в коллекции MyObservableCollection строки становилась невыделяемыми, остальные строки можно выделять. Возможно ли это сделать и как?

Тип коллекции:

```
public class MyType
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public string TypeText {get; set;}
   public bool ReadOnly {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я делал это при помощи конвертера

```
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Style.Triggers>
                   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=field, Converter={StaticResource UnselectRowConverter}}" Value="True">
                      <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGray" />
                   </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Осталось только реализовать логику блокировки строк

Comment: Суть не в этом суть в том, чтобы привязать свойство MyType.ReadOnly в биндинг. А я не знаю как это сделать. Т.к. биндинг его не видит

Comment: <DataGridTextColumn Header="ReadOnly" Binding="{Binding ReadOnly, Mode=OneWay}" Width="10*" />, если во ViewModel это свойство у вас есть, то делайте его bool и вешайте конвертер. С binding проблем не должно быть.

Comment: Его нет там, но оно есть в коллекции, я пытаюсь его вытянуть через {Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Path=Item,
                        Converter={StaticResource AssemblyTypeToBoolConverter}} но пока безуспешно

Comment: Зачем конвертер? У автора вопроса за блокировку отвечает свойство `ReadOnly`. Т.е. достаточно написать так: https://gist.github.com/FoggyFinder/13a0b00b9a411f78164dcf68e22171d7

Comment: Написал тестовый пример - все работает, как и ожидалось.

Comment: Свойство ReadOnly он не видит. Вот скрин http://uploads.ru/JgG7X.png , но ниже на скрине его видит. Как сделать чтобы биндинге DataTrigger тоже видно было?

Comment: @user2455111 Вы просто стиль применяете не там